Is there any OpenRewrite script for Kotlin-based Spring Boot 2 --> 3
There are those cool OpenRewrite scripts for migrating Spring Boot 2 to Spring Boot 3. Like this one here: https://docs.openrewrite.org/recipes/java/spring/boot3/upgradespringboot_3_2.
Is there by any chance something similar for Kotlin-based Spring Boot 2 projects. I searched both the OpenRewrite catalogue and Google but couldn't find anything useful. But maybe I missed some good resource?

Have you already tried running that exact recipe against your Kotlin project? We map Java, Kotlin and Groovy back to the same model, such that the migration steps should all just work.
One exception is that we do not yet support Gradle Kotlin scripts: https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite/issues/3291
Shannon is having a look at that though; so be sure to keep an eye on developments:
https://github.com/shanman190/rewrite-gradle-experimental
If you find anything else not yet matched let us know through the GitHub Issues, and we'll try to get that sorted, or ask you to help :) : https://github.com/openrewrite/rewrite-spring/issues

Thanks for the hint, when running it via Maven, it gets stuck while "[INFO] Running recipe(s)..." and just remains there forever.

Using -X to get Maven to verbose mode I see it's getting stuck while downloading libs. So not Kotlin related then, thanks!

Hmm; yes that downloading libraries sounds curious; feel free to show up in our Slack if you'd like to ask more questions
